# ArrayList Comparator compareTo

Tags: sorting, collections, arraylist, comparator

I have an arraylist of `Processes` in which i want to sort them according to their `arrival time` the problem is that I can't seem to code my `Comparator` well. Below is my code:

```
ArrayList<Process> pArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int x = 0; x<processTable.getRowCount(); x++){
                int pID = Integer.parseInt(processTable.getValueAt(x,0).toString());
                int aT = Integer.parseInt(processTable.getValueAt(x,1).toString());
                int bT = Integer.parseInt(processTable.getValueAt(x,2).toString());
                Process temp = new Process(bT, aT, pID);
                totalBT += bT;
                pArray.add(temp);
            }
            //sort by arrival time
            Collections.sort(pArray, new Comparator<Process>(){
                    int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
                        return o1.getAt() - o2.getAt();
                    }
                    boolean equals(Process obj) {

                    }
                });

            try{
                System.out.print("ha");
                pArray = doRR(new Integer(rr1Q.getValue().toString()), pArray, totalBT);

            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    System.out.println("Process ended due to interruption");
            }
```

The following error pops up:

```
compare(Process,Process) in <anonymous my.CpuGui.CpuGui$ButtonHandler$1> cannot implement compare(T,T) in Comparator
                    int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
```

Can anyone explain what it says?

Comment: As an aside, note that using the `-` shortcut for returning the comparison result can be dangerous because subtraction can overflow back into positive values.  It's usually best to use `Integer.compare(o1.getAt(), o2.getAt())` unless you can guarantee the range of the values will be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the error message is verbatim what I would expect, but your `compare` method cannot reduce the visibility of the method defined in the interface.

Declare `compare` as `public` and it should work (after you get rid of the pointless and erroneous `equals` method of course).

```
Collections.sort(pArray, new Comparator<Process>(){
    public int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
        return o1.getAt() - o2.getAt();
    }
});
```

Comment: that i did not notice, and yeah i was thinking of using the equals but then i found your answer, thanks :)